# java ee jdbc jstl servlet connection to db

Tags: jdbc, servlets

hi guys hope you re doing well please i ve connect a file with class name singletonconnection to my database and it s all working and i created a class to implement some sql querys like selet from and insert into . i tested this in a class test and it is working i can insert and select an assistant but when i use jstl and servlet to insert an assistant using a form it gives me this mistake on the page . `java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.sql.Connection.prepareStatement(String)" because "conn" is null"`. please if you know the answer don t hesitate to comment it .thank you

i try to write describe a probleme and i m looking for an answer

Comment: How did you get a connection? Show the code.

Comment: If you have loaded your driver class from the jar driver read the API docs classes and do  java.sql.Connection conn = java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(...   ...)    then do conn..prepareStatement(String)

Comment: Quote from 1st abovelinked duplicate: *"Please also note that it's very important to throw an exception so that the code execution is immediately blocked, instead of suppressing it or merely printing the stack trace and then continuing the rest of the code."*. This is the primer root cause of your problem. Go fix it. The 2nd duplicate explains the correct way in case you're using Tomcat instead of a normal Jakarta EE server (because a normal JEE server offers JPA out the box which in turn completely eliminates the need for low-level fiddling with plain JDBC).